# Why base64 string sent as param changing length after decoding it on server side?

Tags: post, flask, base64, decode, encode

On the client side I am reading an image file and encoding it in base64, sending it to as an URL param.

```
img = open("file.png", "rb").read()
print len(img)
img = img.encode("base64")
print len(img)
print len(img.decode("base64"))
```

Prints `252235`, `340742` and `252235`.

On server side decoding the received str couldn't yield the same result. I am posting the encoded base64 as "http://url.com/test?image=img_str".

```
img = flask.request.args["image"]
print len(img)
img = img.decode("base64")
print len(img)
```

Prints `340742` which is perfectly fine and `248176` which should actually be the original length. Is image param modifying during the post request? How to do this without using files param in requests or any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured this out!

While sending the encoded string as an URL parameter, "+" in the string are converting into " ". So, had to `encoded_base64.replace(" ", "+")` before decoding. And it worked!